# Allure Report: no data generated for JUnit framework

Tags: maven, testing, junit, report, allure

Our team is using JUnit as base test framework for a large and old project. We recently migrated to Maven and we decided to try a new report for JUnit called **[Allure](http://github.com/allure-framework/)**. We copied dependencies and plugins to our **pom.xml** from the following **[example](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-junit-example)** but no XML data is generated in **target/** folder. No warnings or errors are issued in Maven output. Does anybody know how could it be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Which version of JUnit are you using?** There's a warning in Allure **[documentation](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/wiki/JUnit)** stating that Allure only works with JUnit 4. This is because Allure gets all information about tests using **[RunListener](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.html)** interface which only appeared in JUnit 4.

Comment: So when you're using JUnit 3 the run listener just is never used and thus we can't issue an error or warning.